# Style for references from Mendeley

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, mendeley

I have overleaf sync with Mendeley and I would like to print references but in citation style from Mendeley, how should I do it?

Comment: There is no easy way to use [CSL](https://citationstyles.org) in LaTeX, so you need to customise Bib(La)TeX yourself

Comment: And how should I start please?

Comment: **(1)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509 and **(2)** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ (Disclaimer: I made the video).